# extract the content of a dropdown menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I would like to extract the content of a drop down menu on a certain site (link below)... it consist of two drop down menus:
first: cities in a certain country, once a city is selected
the second drop down menu changes accordingly to display the districts in the city selected in the first.

I would like to download both... 
http://crm.sp.com.sa/addressrequests/default.aspx

is there any chrome or firefox plugin that can extract these values into .csv or text file?

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have gone through the source code of the given website.

The **City source** could be breaken up into like this

```
<ul id="cmbCity_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
<li>الرياض</li><li>جدة</li><li>تاروت</li><li>سيهات</li><li>الظهران</li><li>الدمام</li><li>مكة المكرمة</li><li>الخبر</li><li>الجبيل</li><li>القطيف</li><li>المدينة المنورة</li><li>بريدة</li><li>ابها</li><li>تبوك</li><li>حائل</li><li>جازان</li><li>نجران</li><li>الباحة</li><li>سكاكا</li><li>خميس مشيط</li><li>بيشة</li><li>النماص</li><li>محايل</li><li>ظهران الجنوب</li><li>سراة عبيدة</li><li>احد رفيده</li><li>بلقرن</li><li>المجاردة</li><li>تثليث</li><li>بللسمر</li><li>المخواة</li><li>المندق</li><li>عنيزة</li><li>الرس</li><li>المذنب</li><li>البكيرية</li><li>البدائع</li><li>رياض الخبراء</li><li>النبهانية</li><li>الشماسية</li><li>تيماء</li><li>املج</li><li>الوجه</li><li>حقل</li><li>ضبا</li><li>صبيا</li><li>ابو عريش</li><li>بيش</li><li>فرسان</li><li>صامطة</li><li>احد المسارحة</li><li>شرورة</li><li>يدمة</li><li>ثار</li><li>حبونا</li><li>بدر الجنوب</li><li>القريات</li><li>دومة الجندل</li><li>عرعر</li><li>رفحاء</li><li>طريف</li><li>الدرعية</li><li>الدوادمي</li><li>القويعية</li><li>ثادق</li><li>المجمعة</li><li>الخرج</li>
<li>شقراء</li><li>حريملاء</li><li>الزلفي</li><li>حوطة بني تميم</li><li>المزاحمية</li><li>السليل</li><li>رماح</li><li>عفيف</li><li>الحريق</li><li>ساجر</li><li>ضرما</li><li>الغاط</li><li>الطائف</li><li>القنفذة</li><li>الليث</li><li>رابغ</li><li>الجموم</li><li>رنية</li><li>تربة</li><li>الخرمة</li><li>خليص</li><li>الكامل</li><li>النعيرية</li><li>حفر الباطن</li><li>ينبع</li><li>العلا</li><li>بدر</li><li>الحناكية</li><li>راس تنورة</li><li>بقيق</li><li>الخفجي</li><li>قرية العليا</li><li>صفوى</li><li>الدلم</li><li>ثول</li><li>عيون الجواء</li><li>الغزالة</li><li>بقعاء</li><li>الشنان</li><li>تربه</li><li>البشائر</li><li>عسفان</li><li>خيبر</li><li>الهفوف والمبرز</li><li>عنك</li><li>الحزم</li><li>مدينة الملك عبدالله الاقتصادية</li><li>الخرخير</li><li>الهياثم</li><li>نعجان</li><li>الوديعة</li><li>ملهم</li><li>ليلى</li><li>الحصمة</li><li>الخارش</li><li>السهي</li><li>رمادا</li><li>روان</li><li>مهد الذهب</li><li>نعام</li><li>القصب</li><li>فيفاء</li><li>حرمة</li></ul>
```

Secondly the District source could be breaken up like this:

```
<ul id="cmbDistrict_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">
        <li> الغنامية</li><li>احد</li><li>اشبيلية</li><li>الازدهار</li><li>الاسكان</li><li>الاندلس</li><li>البديعة</li><li>البرية</li><li>البطحاء</li><li>التعاون</li><li>الجرادية</li><li>الجزيرة</li><li>الجنادرية</li><li>الحائر</li><li>الحزم</li><li>الحمراء</li><li>الخالدية</li><li>الخزامى</li><li>الخليج</li><li>الدار البيضاء</li><li>الدحو</li><li>الدريهمية</li><li>الدفاع</li><li>الدوبية</li><li>الديرة</li><li>الرائد</li><li>الربوة</li><li>الربيع</li><li>الرحمانية</li><li>الرفيعة</li><li>الرمال</li><li>الرماية</li><li>الروابي</li><li>الروضة</li><li>الريان</li><li>الزهراء</li><li>الزهرة</li><li>السعادة</li><li>السفارات</li><li>السلام</li><li>السلام</li><li>السلي</li><li>السليمانية</li><li>السويدي</li><li>السويدي الغربي</li><li>الشرفية</li><li>الشرق</li><li>الشفا</li><li>الشميسي</li><li>الشهداء</li><li>الصالحية</li><li>الصحافة</li><li>الصفا</li><li>الصناعية</li><li>الضباط</li><li>العارض</li><li>العريجاء</li><li>العريجاء الغربية</li><li>العريجاء الوسطى</li><li>العزيزية</li><li>العقيق</li><li>العليا</li><li>العماجية</li><li>العمل</li><li>العود</li><li>الغدير</li><li>الفاخرية</li><li>الفاروق</li><li>الفلاح</li><li>الفوطة</li><li>الفيحاء</li><li>الفيصلية</li><li>القادسية</li><li>القدس</li><li>القرى</li><li>القيروان</li><li>المؤتمرات</li><li>المحمدية</li><li>المدينة الصناعية الجديدة</li><li>المربع</li><li>المرسلات</li><li>المرقب</li><li>المروة</li><li>المروج</li><li>المشاعل</li><li>المصانع</li><li>المصفاة</li><li>المصيف</li><li>المعذر</li><li>المعذر الشمالي</li><li>المعكال</li><li>المعيزلة</li><li>المغرزات</li><li>الملز</li><li>الملقا</li><li>الملك عبدالعزيز</li><li>الملك عبدالله</li><li>الملك فهد</li><li>الملك فيصل</li><li>المناخ</li><li>المنار</li><li>المنصورة</li><li>المنصورية</li><li>المهدية</li><li>المونسية</li><li>الناصرية</li><li>النخيل</li><li>الندى</li><li>النرجس</li><li>النزهة</li><li>النسيم الشرقي</li><li>النسيم الغربي</li><li>النظيم</li><li>النفل</li><li>النموذجية</li><li>النهضة</li><li>النور</li><li>الهدا</li><li>الواحة</li><li>الوادي</li><li>الورود</li><li>الوزارات</li><li>الوسيطاء</li><li>الوشام</li><li>الياسمين</li><li>اليرموك</li><li>اليمامة</li><li>ام الحمام الشرقي</li><li>ام الحمام الغربي</li><li>ام الشعال</li><li>ام سليم</li><li>بدر</li><li>بنبان</li><li>ثليم</li><li>جامعة الامام محمد بن سعود الاسلامية</li><li>جامعة الملك سعود</li><li>جبرة</li><li>جرير</li><li>حطين</li><li>خشم العان</li><li>ديراب</li><li>سكيرينة</li><li>سلطانة</li><li>شبرا</li><li>صلاح الدين</li><li>صياح</li><li>ضاحية نمار</li><li>طويق</li><li>طيبة</li><li>ظهرة البديعة</li><li>ظهرة لبن</li><li>ظهرة نمار</li><li>عتيقة</li><li>عرقة</li><li>عريض</li><li>عكاظ</li><li>عليشة</li><li>غبيرة</li><li>غرناطة</li><li>قرطبة</li><li>لبن</li><li>مطار الملك خالد</li><li>منفوحة</li><li>منفوحة الجديدة</li><li>نمار</li><li>هيت</li>
    </ul>
```

Replace the < li> & < /li> in notepad++ with , and save it as .csv for creation of csv

Or

Save the whole Page and using this HTMLAsText v1.11 tool to convert the whole page into txt and grab the relevant content of city and district

Tool Link  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/htmlastext.html

Comment: the problem is when I change the city, it updates on the site but does not update on the page source? any ideas of how to get the districts if I change the city?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Did not have access to the correct link when writing this. Turned out the drop down wasn't actually a `<select>` element, so the below won't work in this case.

---

I think your easiest option is to right click on the drop down box, select **Inspect Element** (Chrome), right click `<select>...</select>` and chose **Copy as HTML**. Then you strip the HTML tags with a tool of your choice. For example: http://www.striphtml.com/

Now you should have all the options as text. Copy them into a file of your choice.

This will probably give you a list of options with spaces between them, like so:

```
optiona optionb optionc
```

which may not be desired. But using **Notepad++** or any other editor with a bit more advanced replace options should provide you with the functionality to replace spaces with newlines (`\r\n`).

```
optiona
optionb
optionc
```

If your options have spaces in them already, you may have to insert a separator before stripping the HTML. Depending on the format of your copied HTML, it might work to replace `">` with `">"` and `</` with `"</` to give you the following result after stripping HTML tags:

```
"option a" "option b" "option c"
```

Replace `" "` with `\r\n` and remove any remaining `"` by replacing `"` with nothing.

```
option a
option b
option c
```